# Dynamic Parameters Based on Decision Variables

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

Is there a way to have a cost parameter c[i,j] dependent on the decision variable (amount of flow) x[i,j] sent on arc (i,j)? So that c[i,j]*x[i,j] is dependent on the amount of flow, more flow = less cost incurred to traverse arc (i,j).

Or would that make c[i,j] a decision variable as well and therefore make the program non-linear? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a couple choices and still keep it linear.  You can make a "piecewise linear" cost function that has many breakpoints/slopes in it.  Search for "piecewise" here or in the dox.  It is a bit of work, and involves using the `kernel` module.  Or if you just have one or two breakpoints in your model where the marginal cost changes, you can introduce one or two additional variables to account for the "overage" and tax/discount it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution can be the following:

1. Make a finite level of flow, for e.g: f1,f2,f3; f3>f2>f1
2. Calculate the difference of actual flow from the flow levels. For e.g.: del_f = f2-x[i,j] , if x[i,j] >f1, x[i,j]<f3
3. Now, based on this difference, you can have a predefined level of cost.